# Configure an app's entry point to redirect to different entry points in Angular based on authentication

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following logic and I'm curious what's the best way for configuring an Angular app for splitting the entry point based on a user's authentication state.

For example, if the user goes to `example.com`, I'd want for the following to happen:

- If user is authenticated

  - render an app root that has a special header and footer shared across the entire app with the a `ui-view` in the middle for swapping out views.
  - route the user to `home`
- If user is not authenticated

  - render an app root that has a basic header and footer shared across these not authenticated pages with the a `ui-view` in the middle for swapping out views.
  - route the user to `landing`

Answer (score 0):

Create a template for your landing page and your authenticated page like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div ui-view="landing-header"></div>
    <div ui-view="landing-content"></div>
    <div ui-view="landing-footer"></div>
</div>
```

Then created separate states that stem from some main (root) state and re-direct the user accordingly throughout your application.

```
$stateProvider.state('root.landing', {
          url: '/landing',
          views: {
              'landing-header': {
                  templateUrl: 'landing/header.template.html'
              },
              'landing-content': {
                  templateUrl: 'landing/login.template.html'
              },
              'landing-footer': {
                  templateUrl: 'landing/footer.template.html'
              }
          }
      })
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm a bit confused on how to go about this. For example, I'd like that if a user is logged into, for them to see a different header and footer and if they are not, then show a different header and footer.

Comment: @Detuned, The example provided shows you the _what_. As far as the _how_, your specific application logic to handle authentication and redirection, you'll have to figure out how you want to do that on your own.